# Hiding any option or menu from menubar

Tags: categories

Just after logging in through the 'Login' menu when any valid user will reach to the profile page that time the 'Login menu will be hidden in a wordpress theme. That means after logging him/herself in he/she can't see the 'Login' menu.

Comment: From which menu? Do you mean `wp_nav_menu`?

Comment: So, whats the question?